# ASP.NET Server.MapPath and SharePoint Document Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have a C# application that needs to populate a list of all the filenames within a particular SharePoint web environment, in which there is a specific document library from which I have to read all the filenames.

Let's say the URL for the document library in question is "http://example.com/lib.aspx".

If I used Server.MapPath like so:

```
Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("http://example.com/lib.aspx"), SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

This would effectively treat the document library as a physical pathname and successfully populate the an array of filenames, correct?

I don't currently have the ability to test this and I am wondering if this operation would be valid; in other words, the filenames would (most likely) be indexed successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't work at all. The documents in the library are not located in the server's file system.

If you're enumerating all files in the library, then you can use the [Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.items) property of the [library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460729) and for each item, use the [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.file) property to retrieve the [SPFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile) associated with the item.